# node.js client side javascript templates (?)

Tags: node.js, express

My client-side JS is getting really big. I am using Express with Jade. Is there any change of making client-side JS templates?

Those templates (bits of code in separate files) should be concatenated at runtime to a one single file and appended to body's footer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

shotenjin.js may help you.

https://raw.github.com/kwatch/tenjin/javascript/javascript/lib/shotenjin.js

I have to confess that I'm author of above code. If it doesn't help you, let me know what is wrong for you. Thank you.